# Was Sam Carter's fancy flip phone an existing model, or based on one?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, props

I was just re-watching the *Stargate SG-1* episode "Threads". As Carter finds herself in an awkward moment with Jack and his recently found companion at his backyard barbecue, she is interrupted by her cell phone. To answer the call, she takes out something looking more like a woman's compact than a phone.

Was she holding a real cell phone? If it was a studio prop, was it modeled on a real cell phone commercially available at the time? If so (real or imitation), what was the real cell phone make and model? It seems to me so unusual as to perhaps be a product placement, but if so, a very subtle one.

[image: Sam takes a call]

[image: Sam and her flip phone]

Comment: She also uses this phone in SG1: Covenant - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKTW9.png

Answer (score 15):

Propworx sold the (screen-used) phone in [an auction](https://www.stargate-fusion.com/fiches/6067-telephone-portable-du-lt-colonel-carter.html).

> **Carter's Cell Phone:**
>
> Cell phone [used by actress Amanda Tapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKTW9.png) as 'Samantha Carter' in
> Season 8 episode SG-1, 'Covenant'."
>
> Silver and red mobile phone with extension antenna. Delivered in a burgundy fabric case. The device is functional. Measures approx. 3in x 2in x 1in, 3.25in long antenna. Made in Korea by Samsung.
>
> [image]

---

It seems to be most likely a Samsung [SCH-A220](https://manualzz.com/doc/866579/samsung-sch-a220-user-guide) which looks identical

[image] [image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in the text from the propworx auction and a better photo of the phone. It's definitely not the T100 and the other phone has an incorrect speaker form, so it must be the A220. Great find!